# PL/SQL, find current directory of executng file in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there anyway I can get the current directory of the executing file in Oracle SQL?

The equivalent to this in java would be
     `File currentDirectory = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());`

I understand that this is difficult in Oracle SQL because it may just return the server filepath.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "current directory" in PL/SQL. The code is run on the server and thus run by the Oracle process that runs the database. The concept of a "current directory" makes no sense for that. Plus there is no "file" that is being executed in PL/SQL

Comment: Can you give example of your execution and what you expect in more details

Comment: Any work arounds?

Comment: *"Any work arounds?"* Actually we're waiting for you to explain what you're trying to achieve. We've already told you *"the current directory of the executing file"* means nothing in the context of PL/SQL. There is no file, there is no directory, it's all just code inside a database. So: please explain what you're doing and what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually mean "when executing a script via SQL*PLUS" rathen than "PL/SQL", then the question makes more sense.

You might find this script useful..

http://orasql.org/2015/06/26/sqlplus-tips-7-how-to-find-current-script-directory/

It's an interesting bit of lateral thinking. Here's what I cam up with after reading it

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Oct 11 16:59:38 2021
Version 19.11.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> DEF NON_EXISTANT_FILE = '_nonExistantFile.sql';
SQL> --
SQL> spool _CURRENT_PATH.txt
SQL> @@&NON_EXISTANT_FILE
SP2-0310: unable to open file "c:\development\yadamu\scratch\oracle\_nonExistantFile.sql"
SQL> spool off;
SQL>
SQL> VAR RESULT VARCHAR2(1024);
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     C_SP2_0310_ERROR CONSTANT VARCHAR2(200) := 'SP2-0310: unable to open file ';
  3  begin
  4    -- the @@ expression must be in separate line as follows
  5    :RESULT := '
  6  @_CURRENT_PATH.txt
  6  SQL> @@&NON_EXISTANT_FILE
  7  SP2-0310: unable to open file "c:\development\yadamu\scratch\oracle\_nonExistantFile.sql"
  8  SQL> spool off;
  9  ';
 10    :RESULT := SUBSTR(:RESULT,(INSTR(:RESULT,C_SP2_0310_ERROR)+LENGTH(C_SP2_0310_ERROR)+1));
 11    :RESULT := SUBSTR(:RESULT,1,INSTR(:RESULT,'&NON_EXISTANT_FILE')-2);
 12    end;
 13  /
old   6: SQL> @@&NON_EXISTANT_FILE
new   6: SQL> @@_nonExistantFile.sql
old  11:   :RESULT := SUBSTR(:RESULT,1,INSTR(:RESULT,'&NON_EXISTANT_FILE')-2);
new  11:   :RESULT := SUBSTR(:RESULT,1,INSTR(:RESULT,'_nonExistantFile.sql')-2);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> PRINT :RESULT

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c:\development\yadamu\scratch\oracle

SQL>
```